# Is it a good idea to deploy self-made python modules into working environment by virtualenv?

Tags: python

Lately I was working on changing the deployment of our in-house python modules. Those modules are for in-house usage only. Our previous deployment is to put all modules into somewhere (ex, **/gozilla/pylib**) and set the global environment variable, **PYTHONPATH** point to it.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to make use of **virtualenv** for this kind of deployment? Or some other alternative ways to do that, especially making use of **setup.py** mechanism with possibility to do auto unit-test, doc-gen, ...?

**Update**

For making use of **PYTHONPATH**, it works well except that we have to do our own copy-n-paste for deployment and there is no any support for unit-test, doc-gen, module-dependency...

For making use of **virtualenv** as deployment tool, other (stand-alone) python scripts are asked to enter **virtual env mode by source ...bin/activate** or by manually invoke **execfile(activate_this, dict(_*file*_=activate_this))** in the very beginning of their own script. Is it possible to prevent this kind of **manually entering virtualenv mode by execfile** for each Python scripts?

That's what I get right now ;) and I am looking for other suggested ways to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea, since you get all the advantages you already mentioned.

I can recommend using Paver (which makes setuptools decent to extend), and also integrates things like unit tests, Sphinx, etc. into the build process.

Regarding the auto-activation of the venv, if you add "console_scripts" entry points to your project's setup, then setuptools will automatically create script stubs that do just that — on any supported target platform.

Then you can either write an installer script that creates a virtualenv on the target machine using pre-built eggs, or package a whole venv into an OS package (e.g. .deb). There's tools for that, too, in various stages of maturity.

*) http://paver.github.com/paver/

Comment: still trying to figure out how to make use of paver ;)